# change root@<name> in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: linux, shell, command, ubuntu-18.04

On my machine i'm getting "root@umar" that I want to change to "root@junaid". I have tried running different commands. They do change my username but above mentioned name is not changing. 
[image]

See in above image. User I'm logged in as is "Junaid". But before that there is "root@umar" that I want to be changed to "root@junaid". Solutions I have tried change my current username that I'm loggedIn as.

Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"umar" is the hostname. So you should change it to get prompt like "root@junaid"
To do this on the fly you should exec next command:

```
sudo hostname junaid

sudo vi /etc/hostname
```

(to update the hostname there)
and the same in `hosts` file

```
sudo vi /etc/hosts
```

If you run commands as root you do not need to have `sudo`